# how to use multiple mozilla browser versions in windows 7  

Tags: firefox, testing, browser

present in my current machine i am using Mozilla Firefox 9 so i have small task to check on Firefox 7. 
Any body help how to check multiple versions at a time for example IE tester if any one give reference related to my requirement. it is much use full for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: [MultiFirefox](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/)